# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined. Is npm the issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
res.send('INDEX PAGE');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I keep getting this error, I've even downgraded my express to V3.21.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 3):

The Express V3.X API reference doesn't have **express.Router**. [API Reference](https://expressjs.com/en/3x/api.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

```
var express = require('express');
var app= express();

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
res.send('INDEX PAGE');
});

module.exports = app;
```